# Portlets, HttpSession and Thread-Safety

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, session-state, portlet

Our portlets keep state in the HttpSession, which is shared by all request processing threads for the same session.

The portlet spec (JSR-168) writes:

> **PLT.5.2.4.3 Multithreading Issues During Request Handling**
>
> The portlet container handles concurrent requests to the same portlet by concurrent
>   execution of the request handling methods on different threads. Portlet developers must
>   design their portlets to handle concurrent execution from multiple threads from within the
>   `processAction` and `render` methods at any particular time.

I wonder how I am supposed to achieve that? Sure, I can use synchronization to achieve mutual exclusion during both `processAction` and `render`, but I don't see how I can enforce atomicity of request processing as a whole. In particular, I worry about the following scenario:

- Thread 1 executes `processAction`, loading data into the session for later rendering
- Thread 2 executes `processAction`, discarding that data from the session
- Thread 1 executes `render`, reading the data to render from the session, and throws a NullPointerException because the prepared data is no longer there ...

How is that scenario usually prevented? In particular, when using the JBoss portlet bridge to adapt JSF to a Portlet environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that if there are two portlets operating on the same data, especially one reading it while the other deletes it, there's most likely a serious flaw in the design.

You might then want to store the data per portlet/thread, i.e. if portlet1 reads some data you should write lock it until reading is finished and put it into the session using a unique key.

If it is legal to delete data that should be rendered, then you should account for that and check again during `render`.

Comment: You misunderstand: It's the same portlet, the server processes two requests concurrently because the user clicks on a second button while the preceeding click is still being processed. And no, the state must be visible across requests (because subsequent requests might operate on the same data and I don't want to reload it from the database), so I can't bind it to the thread.

Comment: Well, it depends on the use case, but I'd not allow the user to trigger another action before the current is finished. Example: the user loads some data and then clicks on 'delete' with out actually seeing it. That would be very error prone, from a business view point. If this still can happen, well then you'd need to account for that - like check for the data still being there while rendering as well as locking it during that operation.

Comment: So even if I managed to synchronize the entire request processing on the server, that would still fall short of making the actual business transaction atomic, and anything making the business transaction atomic will trivially solve the concurency issue on the server. That's a very good point, and I shall therefore look into doing something on the client side. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might also check whether there is currently an action being executed for a specific portlet on the server side, just in case client side checks fail or circumvented somehow.